# Format of the basic CGI protocol. Examples

Tags: c++, c, cgi, cgi-bin

I am writing a C CGI program

For GET requests, I assume all the information is somehow stored in getenv(). My question is, what does this array look like a most basic CGI request from the webserver. With two prarameters e.g. username= and password=.

For POST request, I am unsure. I've read that stuff is handled on standard input. What do these lines that are passed to a CGI program via standard input (from the webserver) look like?

Pointing me to a verbose RFC is unhelpful.

Any book? I am specifically interested in the low-level details of the protocol. I already know how to write CGI apps with helper libs... I just need to know the semantics of those helper libs.

Comment: RFC 3875: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3875

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`envp` is not standard (well, not ISO C or C++ standard anyway, though POSIX may have something for it).

However, `envp` is pretty much the same format as `argv` escept it doesn't have a controlling `argc` to limit it.

Each `envp[x]` will be of the form `"key=value"` where the `key` is the environment variable name and the `value` is its value, surprisingly enough :-)

You should process the elements sequentially until you get a NULL pointer, something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]) {
    int i = 0;
    while (envp[i] != NULL)
        printf ("[%s]\n", envp[i++]);
    return 0;
}
```

The [Wikipedia entry for CGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) gives further details, hopefully without swamping you with too much information like a verbose RFC would.

Copying the relevant stuff to make this answer self-contained:

- Server specific variables:

  - SERVER_SOFTWARE — name/version of HTTP server.
  - SERVER_NAME — host name of the server, may be dot-decimal IP address.
  - GATEWAY_INTERFACE — CGI/version.
- Request specific variables:

  - SERVER_PROTOCOL — HTTP/version.
  - SERVER_PORT — TCP port (decimal).
  - REQUEST_METHOD — name of HTTP method (see above).
  - PATH_INFO — path suffix, if appended to URL after program name and a slash.
  - PATH_TRANSLATED — corresponding full path as supposed by server, if PATH_INFO is present.
  - SCRIPT_NAME — relative path to the program, like /cgi-bin/script.cgi.
  - QUERY_STRING — the part of URL after ? character. May be composed of *name=value pairs separated with ampersands (such as var1=val1&var2=val2…) when used to submit form data transferred via GET method as defined by HTML application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
  - REMOTE_HOST — host name of the client, unset if server did not perform such lookup.
  - REMOTE_ADDR — IP address of the client (dot-decimal).
  - AUTH_TYPE — identification type, if applicable.
  - REMOTE_USER used for certain AUTH_TYPEs.
  - REMOTE_IDENT — see ident, only if server performed such lookup.
  - CONTENT_TYPE — MIME type of input data if PUT or POST method are used, as provided via HTTP header.
  - CONTENT_LENGTH — similarly, size of input data (decimal, in octets) if provided via HTTP header.
  - Variables passed by user agent (HTTP_ACCEPT, HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE, HTTP_USER_AGENT, HTTP_COOKIE and possibly others) contain values of corresponding HTTP headers and therefore have the same sense.

Beyond that level of detail, you're probably going to *have* to look into the RFCs, I'm afraid. A search for RFC3875 on Google should locate it.

Specifically, for `POST`, the environment variables are included before the first blank line of the request (the one that introduces the message body). They have the form:

```
Content-Type: application/wonderful_app_by_pax
Content-Length: 314159
```

where the key is case-insensitive and the value follows the colon.

Comment: That **is** the CGI protocol.

Comment: @unixman83, I've updated the answer with more specifics. _More_ specifics than that will probably turn this answer into a copy of the "verbose" RFC so you should probably reference that if you want greater detail :-)

Comment: `extern char **environ;` is the correct, portable (POSIX) way to access the environment variables as an array. `envp` is not. BTW you can just as easily use `getenv`, which is pure C, if you know the variable names you want.